# What can you do with challenges after completing them in an area?

Tags: destiny-2

You eventually get to a point where you get assigned these challenges (kill X many people with Y, or get Z types of kills etc etc) for each planet or event (strikes/crucible etc).

I've completed a bunch of them, but unlike the first time they introduce challenges with Ikora and she rewarded you via a milestone for doing challenges, the ones I've finished since then just sit there when I open the director.

Do we earn anything from doing these? Is it only milestone? Can I turn them in somewhere to earn something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Challenges reset every day. Once you've done them for the day, that's it - you can't complete them again. When you complete them, they typically reward you a token that gives rep.

Basically every activity in the game (going to each planet, strikes, Crucible playlists, etc.) has their own set to challenges. There is also a daily milestone for completing challenges that resets daily ("Complete 5 Challenges", "Complete 3 Strike Challenges", etc.) that rewards a reputation bundle.

If you played the original Destiny, they seem to be Destiny 2's version of bounties.

Comment: Might be worth adding to the answer that 3 challenges per day are for every possible activity (strikes, planets etc) and each day there is a milestone to complete a number of challenges with a rep bundle as a reward.